# What is the definition of $f(a)$ where $a$ is in a unital $C^*$-algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

Suppose that $A$ is a unital C$^*$-algebra. An element $a \in A$ is said to be normal if $a^*a=a^*a$. Further, let $\sigma(a)$ be the spectrum of $a$. I keep seeing these references to $f(a)$ where $f \in C(\sigma(a))$, the set of continuous functions $f: \sigma(a)\to \mathbb{C}$. But what does it mean? $f$ is a $\mathbb{C}-$function on $\sigma(a) \subset \mathbb{C}$! I think there is some sort of identification going on, but I don't know what.

I guess I should be using the condition that $A$ is unital. In that case, let $C^*(a,1)$ denote the $C^*$-algebra generated by $a$, given by $C^*(a,1)= \overline{\mathrm{span}\{(a^*)^ma^n:m,n\ge 0\}}$, which by the Gelfand-Naimark theorem is $*-$isomorphic to $\Sigma(C^*(a,1))$, the set of characters on $C^*(a,1)$ via the Gelfand transform $\Gamma$.

Question: What does $f(a)$ mean for $f \in C(\sigma(a))$? Why should $f(a)$ belong to $A$? I'll be very grateful if someone could explicity write down the map. Thanks!

Comment: This is a consequence of the spectral theorem and is quite surprising.  In fact, the idea extends beyond continuous functions on $\sigma(a)$ to Borel measurable functions!  Think about this in the context of matricies.

Comment: Have the stars in the first equality different meaning  ? In this case, you should use other symbols to avoid confusion. As displayed , it is extremely hard to distinguish them.

Comment: "What is the definition of $f(a)$?" is not a useful title. It says nothing about the subject of the question. Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: If $p$ is a polynomial in two variables then  for $g(z)=p(z,\bar{z})$ the element $g(a)$ is defined as $g(a)=p(a,a^*).$ Moreover $\|g(a)\|=\max\{|g(z)|\,:\, z \in \sigma(a)\}.$  By Stone-Weierstrass theorem for every function $f\in C(\sigma(a))$ there exists a sequence of polynomials  $p_n$ in two variables such that $p_n(z,\bar{z})$ is convergent uniformly to $f$ in the space $C(\sigma(a)).$ Then $p_n(a,a^*)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Its limits defines $f(a).$

Comment: This is called the **continuous functional calculus**: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you observed, $C^*(a,1)$ is isomorphic to continous functions on $\mathrm{Spec}(C^*(a,1))$. The thing is this is homeomorphic to $\mathrm{sp}(a)$, we get this by sending a character $\gamma$ to $\gamma(a)$ (check that the codomain is correct and this is infact a homeomorphism). After we gather all the information, we end up with an isomorphism

$$C(\mathrm{sp}(a)) \cong C^*(a,1) $$

This isomorphism sends the function $1\mapsto 1_A$ (i.e function of all 1s to the identity element of $A$) and sends $\mathrm{id}_{\mathrm{sp}(a)} \mapsto a$. The image of a function $f$ on $\mathrm{sp}(a)$ under this isomorphism is called $f(a)$.

In general this is known as the functional calculus or the spectral theorem.

As an example if $a$ is a positive element of $A$, i.e self adjoint and $\mathrm{sp}(a) \subset [0,\infty)$, then $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is a continuous function on the spectrum and so you can use this isomorphism to get $\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!